# Fake people database for a creditworthiness definition app

Tags: database, data-mining

I have a task to create a decision tree for defining a person's creditworthiness based on their information. I need a database containing about 1000 of persons with their personal information, of course they can be fake. Where can I get this database? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you will never know if they were *really* creditworthy, if it is fake data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Redgate's SQL Data Generator 1.2](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)

This article might be of interest if you do not want to buy a tool:

- [Generate test data using SQL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0405kuznetsov/index.html)

If you have access to the Database Edition of Visual Studio 2008:

- [How Do I: Generate Test Data using Visual Studio Team System Database Edition?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/cc501309)

VS2010 : [Generating Test Data for Databases by Using Data Generators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I know it might be late, but here's the German credit scoring dataset. It contains 1000 observations, and the data is real.

http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/service/datenarchiv/kredit/kredit_e.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Fake name generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/)

You can order bulk data for free from http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php